# How to store some text typed in textarea as a text file in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hello friends I have a laravel project where I am trying to save some text typed in ***textarea*** input element as a text file. And I don't know how to do it. Here is my blade file code and controller code:

Part of Blade file form code

```
<form method="POST" action="/company" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {!! csrf_field() !!}
  <textarea name="description">
    Write something.
  </textarea>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Part of controller code

```
public function store(Request $request){
  $destinationPath='public/company_info';
  $fileName = 'description.txt';


  $request->description->storeAs(
    $destinationPath, $fileName
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the config/filesystem.php

```
    'open' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
        'url' => env('APP_URL'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

In controller:

```
Storage::disk('open')->put('company_info/description.txt', $request->description);
```

Comment: Provided solution works but I wanted to store the file in storage/app/public/company_info directory. But Its still useful.

Comment: 'root' => storage_path(),

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Laravel's File Storage methods.

Your controller will need to alias the Storage namespace:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`

Assuming your file's contents are stored in a variable name $contents, you would then use the following to store the file:

`Storage::put('public/company_info/file.txt', $contents);`

To reference the value the user has submitted via the textarea, you will need to use `$request->input('description')`. Putting that together, you may use something like the following:

`Storage::put('public/company_info/file.txt', $request->input('description'));`

If you haven't already, make sure that the public files are publicly accessible by running the following artisan command:

`php artisan storage:link`

Relevant documentation can be found at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem

Comment: Author asks for saving it in public directory, not storage directory

Comment: In which case you create a symbolic link to the public directory (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk) and specify 'public/file.txt' in the put method. Is this really worthy of a downvote?

Comment: Yes, because you basically wrote "Use Storage::put, here is the link"

Comment: Surya did not specify where they would like to store the file, although the public directory was implied in their code example. I will, however, add a note about how to reference the original value.

Comment: I actually did wanted to store the file in storage/app/public/company_info directory. In my code above I have used storeAs ($destinationPath, $fileName); method, where $destinationPath = 'public/company_info' and this methods actually saves the file in storage/app/public/company_info directory. So It doesn't worth a down vote and the solution provided worked fine. Thank You